# Jquery mouse event alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so the code below works fine if I click outside the #nav div. I was asking if it is possible to just move the mouse away from the #nav div to make it disappear. I don't want to 'click' to hide the div. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKpwV)

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {
        var container = $("#nav");

        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
            container.hide();
        }
    });
```

I tried the mouseenter and mouseleav, but they don't work. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKpwV/1)
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to bind the event handlers to the element involved, not `$(document)`.

Comment: Also try `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave looks like it worked to me. What is the problem?

Comment: mouseleave have worked for me, what's wrong?

Comment: Please don't re-post your question. If the answers you got previously don't work for you then bring that up with the people who posted them, and they might be able to assist you in figuring out what else is wrong with your code.

Comment: try `mouseout` function

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, I agree, and he asked it too.

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave will work when you move your mouse away from the white box where we are testing the function. Move your mouse within the small testing window, it doesnt work

Comment: Well im sorry for that. But actually, the way i saw it, people couldnt solve it. so i thought i bring it up again. sorry

Comment: @MohammedmehdiKhatau They could (and *did*) solve it, though - your second example doesn't use the code that was posted as an answer on your original question. Had you actually tried that it would have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#logo").mouseover(function() { $("#nav").fadeIn("slow"); });

   $("#nav").mouseleave(function (e){
       $(this).fadeOut("slow");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a mouseleave on the Nav i have added it for you check the link below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#logo").mouseenter(function() { $("#nav").fadeIn("slow"); });
});

$("#nav").mouseleave(function (e)
{
       $("#nav").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sKpwV/6/

if you want to make a dropdown menu i sugget you take a look at the link here: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/ it does a dropdown with Pure CSS, so it will also work when the user don't have Javascript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The margin between your `nav` div and `logo` div is causing a problem. When the user directs their mouse between those areas, and you've set a `mouseout` event strictly on the `nav` div, it causes the window to close. The solution is to add a small timeout to allow the user time to navigate through the menu before closing it. This will avoid other cases in which the user accidentally mouses to the edge of the navigation and is maybe a pixel or two outside of the `div`.

Here is the jQuery I used to solve this problem:

```
$('#nav').mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'mouseOutTimer'));
});
$('#nav').mouseout(function () {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'mouseOutTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'mouseOutTimer', setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nav").hide();
    }, 700));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HyUEu/