# What is the alternative for pointerevent in safari browser using react or javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to detect the event and check if its an instance of mouseeevent, wheelevent, touchevent or pointerevent. and return the event. the below code works fine on all browsers except safari.

```
const pointer_device = !window.PointerEvent && !navigator.pointerEnabled ?
```

'Mouse' : 'Pointer';

```
class somecomponent extends React.purecomponent  {

     forward = e => {
         forward_mouse_event(e.nativeEvent, this.get_target()); //here is 
         //where the event is got
     }

    handle_pointer_down = e => {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); 
        if (e.button === main_button && this.left_click_catchers_available()) 
        {
            this.left_down = componentUtils.copy_mouse_event(e.nativeEvent);
            if (this.mousedown_catchers_available()) {
                this.mousedown_event(this.left_down);
            }
         } else if (e.button === secondary_button && 
             this.right_click_catchers_available()) {
                 this.right_down = 
                 componentUtils.copy_mouse_event(e.nativeEvent);
         } else {
             this.forward(e);
         }
     }

     handle_pointer_move = move_event => {
         const held_down_event = this.left_down || this.right_down;
         if (held_down_event) {
             if (this.drag_event_catchers_available()) {
                 this.drag_event(move_event);
             } else if (this.moved_too_far_to_click(held_down_event, 
             move_event)) {
                 this.dispatch(held_down_event);
                 this.left_down = undefined;
                 this.right_down = undefined;
             }
             this.forward(move_event);
         } else {
             this.forward(move_event);
         }
     }

     handle_pointer_up = e => {
         if (e.button === main_button && this.left_down) {
             this.left_click(e);
         } else if (e.button === secondary_button && this.right_down) {
             this.right_click(e);
         } else {
             this.forward(e);
         }
         this.left_down = undefined;
         this.right_down = undefined;
     }

     handle_mouse_leave = () => {
         const held_down_event = this.left_down || this.right_down;
         if (held_down_event && !this.drag_event_catchers_available()) {
             this.dispatch(held_down_event);
             this.left_down = undefined;
             this.right_down = undefined;
         }
     }

     render() {
         const pointing_device_props = {};
         pointing_device_props[`on${pointer_device}Down`] = 
         this.handle_pointer_down;
         pointing_device_props[`on${pointer_device}Up`] = 
         this.handle_pointer_up;
         pointing_device_props[`on${pointer_device}Move`] = 
         this.handle_pointer_move;
         pointing_device_props[`onMouseLeave`] = this.handle_mouse_leave;

         return (
             <div
                 onWheel={this.forward}
                 {...pointing_device_props}
             />);
     }
  }


function copy_mouse_event(event) {
    const event_init = {
       // EventInit
       bubbles: event.bubbles,
       eventPhase: event.eventPhase,

       // UIEventInit
       detail: event.detail,
       view: event.view,

       // EventModifierInit
       altKey: event.altKey,
       ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey
    };

    // initialise MouseEvent data which is shared by wheel, mouse and pointer events
    let mouse_event_init = {};
    if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
        mouse_event_init = {
            ...event_init,
            button: event.button,
            buttons: event.buttons,
            clientX: event.clientX,
            clientY: event.clientY,
            relatedTarget: event.relatedTarget,
            screenX: event.screenX,
            screenY: event.screenY
        };

        if (event instanceof WheelEvent) {
            const wheel_event_init = {
                ...mouse_event_init,
                deltaMode: event.deltaMode,
                deltaX: event.deltaX,
                deltaY: event.deltaY,
                deltaZ: event.deltaZ,
                wheelDelta: event.wheelDelta,
                wheelDeltaX: event.wheelDeltaX,
                wheelDeltaY: event.wheelDeltaY
            };
            return new WheelEvent(event.type, wheel_event_init);
        }
    }

    // try the modern pointer event first, then mouse and touch events
    if (event instanceof PointerEvent) {
        const pointer_event_init = {
            ...mouse_event_init,
            pointerId: event.pointerId,
            width: event.width,
            height: event.height,
        };
        return new PointerEvent(event.type, pointer_event_init);
    } else if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
        return new MouseEvent(event.type, mouse_event_init);
    } else if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {
        //error occurs here only on safari
        const touch_event_init = {
            ...event_init,
            changedTouches: event.changedTouches,
            targetTouches: event.targetTouches,
            touches: event.touches
        };
        return new TouchEvent(event.type, touch_event_init);
    }
    return new MouseEvent(event.type, mouse_event_init);
}

function forward_mouse_event(event, target) {
    target.dispatchEvent(copy_mouse_event(event));
}
```

On safari seems like the event type is pointermove...so what condition should i check for....i am not sure which instanceof event it belongs to.

Within copy_mouse_event_method it doesnt it doesnt enter into any of the conditions. what condition should i check for the event type pointermove.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**
instead i returned mouseevent for safari as in above code and it works if i use mouse. but doesnt work for the keyboard mouse pad. how can i fix it.

Comment: Did you checked `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` ?? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160427/jquery-mouse-event-alternative

Comment: thanks but why is mouseenter and mouse leave needed? what instance of event does event of type pointermove belong to in safari?

Comment: Please refer mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events

Comment: Safari doesn't support pointermove event, so that's probably not a legit one you get there. Otherwise, it would fall in `instanceof PointerEvent`. Where do the events come from?

Comment: thanks i have edited my code. the events are got from the somecomponent component

Comment: returning mouseevent works with mouse but not with keyboard mouse pad. could you help me fix this. thanks.